# Is there any way I can improve my question about setting a NSApplication custom class?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question: [Why does calling NSApplication.shared directly fail to instantiate the class specified by the Principal Class in Info.plist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77423931/16217248)

Originally the question was not the most 'reproducible' question as I got an answer that specified I must specify a specific setting, but I later learned that that setting was appearing to be ignored in my old project, but was working in a 'fresh' project. So I managed to reproduce the issue in a modified blank project and edited the question detailing the minimal reproducible example including **all** the changes I made to the blank template to reproduce the issue.

However, despite this, my question still remains of negative score and inadequately answered despite my efforts to convey a minimal reproducible example and that the problem was novel and not solved. Are there any more details or refinements that specific question needs to be clear and answerable?

---

**Edit:** I have stripped down on the less relevant details on my question as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429573/is-there-any-way-i-can-improve-my-nsapplication-principle-class-question#comment991336_429573). Is there anything else I can do to improve the post?

**I would like to know what is so wrong with my question that even asking what is wrong with my question is a apparently 'poorly researched'/'disagreeable' question. What is obvious to you might not be obvious to others.** Only one actionable issue was brought up in the comments and I have addressed it; anything else?

Comment: I don't understand what you find inadequate about the answer you received.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In short, the answer essentially says 'Do X' but when I try to 'Do X' it only works in a certain case but not in others, and I want to know how to make it work in said other cases. Given that you didn't understand at first, is there any way I can clarify that in my question?

Comment: The main thing that strikes me about the question is that it is about three times as long as I would prefer questions to be at a maximum. I wish I could give more specific help, but the technologies involved are completely foreign to me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Better now?

Comment: Much better, yes.